# Linear Combination to equations by Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let there be two equations such that a+b=0
a-b=1. Now I have just starting learning linear algebra, so from my understanding 0 is a constant vector with components a and b, 1 is also a constant vector with components a and -b. Now when we convert this into matrix form we get. $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 &-1 
\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b 
\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$
Now I do not get how can you do this, 0 was already a vector, how can you make it the component of another vector, also when we open the matrix partially we get, $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$a+$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}$b=$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$
Now I do not get how can you multiply a component get with a vector, also I have seen people take a=1 and they say that we get the vector $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$         but isn't  a also a matrix with $\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$. So whatever you multiply it with the y component gets cancelled. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from my understanding 0 is a constant vector with components a and b, 1 is also a constant vector with components a and -b

No, this is not correct. In this case, $0$ and $1$ are scalars. They are the usual real numbers that you're used to. In fact, none of the symbols in the original equations
$$\begin{cases}a + b = 0 \\ a - b = 1\end{cases}$$
are vectors. Both $a$ and $b$ are (unknown) real numbers, the addition/subtraction here is the standard operations on $\Bbb{R}$ that you've been learning about since you were a child. **There are no vectors here at this stage whatsoever.**

Now, at this point, we can use the tools of linear algebra to help us solve this system. To do so, we need to take this system of linear equations, and express them using the language of linear algebra: vectors and matrices. We can form vectors and matrices by taking real numbers, and putting them as components. Consider the following matrix/vector equation:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
We now have two vectors, and one matrix. Every symbol inside the vectors and matrix are still real numbers. Expanding the left hand side, we get
$$\begin{bmatrix} a + b \\ a - b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
which is immediately equivalent to the system of two linear equations above. We can also write, using the definitions of addition and scalar multiplication of vectors:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a + b \\ a - b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} b \\ -b \end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix},$$
which gives us your partially expanded form:
$$a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, we can indeed try various values of $a$ and $b$, if we wish, so long as we substitute in real numbers. You can indeed try $a = 1$ (and $b = 0$). The result on the left hand side will be:
$$1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + 0\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
I hope this clears up some confusion.

Comment: Yes it clears up a lot of confusion

Comment: But when we plot a and b, we do them like vectors and a and b, like if a=1 b=-1 and we plot this points isnt that a vector?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha If you're forming an $a$-$b$ plane, you could plot the point at $a = 1$ and $b = -1$. In this case, you are really plotting the vector $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$. This is now a new object, different from $a$ and from $b$. The variables $a$ and $b$ are still real numbers, but now they have been used as coordinates for the (new) vector $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: But doesnt that imply that a and b are the components of a vector, which means that they are also vectors?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha No, quite the opposite! It means they are scalars. (Well, actually, we already knew they were scalars. I mean that we can't put vectors as components of other vectors.)

Comment: But for example lets say a=1, does that not mean that go 1 in the x direction assuming a to be the x component

Comment: Doesnt it also have a direction with it?

Comment: No, $a = 1$ means the scalar $a$ is the same as the scalar $1$. It doesn't say anything about vectors. If you are plotting the vectors $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ in the $a$-$b$ plane, then the scalar equality $a = 1$ translates to $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ being on the vertical line (assuming $a$ is the horizontal axis) $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} : a = 1 \right\}$. This set of vectors is not the same as the scalar equation $a = 1$, but is the result of plotting this equation on the $a$-$b$ plane.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Regarding your second question, I would advise not engaging too much with the physics definition of a vector, i.e. a quantity with magnitude and direction, as it is not really a precise definition.

Answer (score 0):

The system of the equations: a + b = 0 and a - b =1 can be converted to the matrix you have listed $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then if you let $X = \begin{bmatrix} a \\b  \end{bmatrix}$. Then the system of equation given, in matrix form, is equivalent to the equation $AX = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$